# What syntax do I need to select an individual row in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `input_data`. I can't figure out how to select an individual row, based on two conditions. My dataframe looks as follows:

```
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close     Volume  Name
0 2006-01-03  77.76  79.35  77.24  79.11    3117200   ABC
1 2006-01-03  51.70  52.58  51.05  52.58    7825700   DEF
```

I can select by date alone, or name alone, but get errors with:

```
print(input_data.loc[(input_data['Date'] == pd.to_datetime('2006-01-03 00:00:00'))and (input_data['Name'] == 'ABC')]).
```

I've tried to mimic the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890844/select-individual-rows-from-multiindex-pandas-dataframe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe) and [here](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/) but no luck.

```
print(input_data.loc[input_data['Date'] == pd.to_datetime('2006-01-03 00:00:00')]) 
print(input_data.loc[input_data['Name'] == 'ABC'])

# Below line doesn't work
print(input_data.loc[(input_data['Date'] == pd.to_datetime('2006-01-03 00:00:00'))and (input_data['Name'] == 'MMM')])
```

Using the date and 'ABC' I want to end up with:

```
0 2006-01-03  77.76  79.35  77.24  79.11    3117200   ABC
```

Simple answers that I can understand are preferred.

Comment: Use `&` not `and`

Comment: Thanks ALollz. Googling tells me that the difference was because 'and' is boolean, while '&' is bitwise, or vice versa. Setting A = 1 and B = 2, and printing out A and B or A & B demonstrates I don't really understand this, but thanks for your correction.

Comment: If you read the solutions in the duplicate they go into extensive depth trying to explain the difference.